# How to create a webapi that returns sqldatareader data in c#?

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am using asp.net core. I need to display the data in the select dropdown in react from web api. WebApi GET method that returns `SQL DataReader`. Reader returns one row with `prodid`, `prodname`, and `proddescr` columns. Please help what the best way to write a get web api that uses `SQL DataReader` for filling the select dropdown in react.

```cs
[HttpGet("{ProductID}")]
public JsonResult GetProductInfo(int ProductID)
{
    var response = GetProductInfo(ProductID);

    return new JsonResult(response);
}

public string GetProductInfo(int Product_ID)
{
    SqlConnection objConnect = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);

    SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand("usp_GetProdInfo", objConnect);

    objCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    objCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Product_ID", SqlDbType.Int, 4));

    objCommand.Parameters["@Product_ID"].Value = intProduct_ID;

    string json = string.Empty;

    List<object> objects = new List<object>();     

    objConnect.Open();

    SqlDataReader reader = objCommand.ExecuteReader();      
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> record = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            record.Add(reader.GetName(i), reader[i]);
        }

        objects.Add(record);
    }

    json =JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objects);

    reader.Close();

    objConnect.Close();

    return json;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with your current implementation?

Comment: Current webApi implementation returns the data. I am not an expert in webapi and react. I am not sure if this is the best approach or not.

Comment: "Best" is a matter of opinion unless you have some specific definition of it. Also, in its current state the question has little or nothing to do with ReactJs or API-specific problems. I can only comment on how you fetch data from your DB. I would look for a library that makes it easier, if you have to do a lot like this.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to  serialize data, Net can do it for you. And it is a very bad programming style to use objects instead of real classes. So return List instead of List

```
public ActionResult<List<Product>> GetProductInfo(int ProductID)
       {

         var response = GetProductInfoList(ProductID);

         if (response != null) return Ok(result)
         else retun BadRequest();

     }

     public List<Product> GetProductInfoList(int Product_ID)
     {
                List<Product> products = new List<Product>();    
                ...fix the code to get typed List<Product> from reader
                return products;
    }
```